# Closing position on a given condition in cTrader

Tags: c#, algorithmic-trading

I have coded a cBot for cTrader. I would like to include a condition to close all the trades if the daily equity (P&L of open positions+P&L closed positions) is <= than a given parameter and then wait until the next day before opening a new position.

I have added the following code:

```
protected override void OnTick()
{            
    double equityChange = CalculateEquityChange(); 
    if (Server.TimeInUtc.Date > lastTradeDate) // Update the daily equity balance
    {
        dailyEquityChange = equityChange;
        lastTradeDate = Server.TimeInUtc.Date;
    }

    double actualchange = equityChange-dailyEquityChange; // Calculate the value
    Print($"Equity Change: {actualchange}"); //To check the values during backtest
        
    foreach (var position in Positions) 
    {               
        if (actualchange <= - DailyChange) // Closing conditions  
        {
            ClosePosition(position);
            Print("Max daily loss");
        }    
    }            
}

private double CalculateEquityChange()
{
    double equityChange = 0;

    foreach (var position in Positions)
    {
        equityChange += position.GrossProfit;
    }

    foreach (var closedPosition in History)
    {
        equityChange += closedPosition.NetProfit;
    }

    return equityChange;
}
```

I expect that when the condition is triggered, the cBot close the position and wait until the next day to set 'actualchange' to 0 and wait for a new entry condition